# Using a PostgreSQL function inside a loop

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, transactions

Suppose I have a PostgreSQL function that takes 2 parameters: id (INT), email (TEXT) and can be called like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(101, 'myemail@gmail.com')
```

I want to run a SELECT query from a table that would return multiple id's:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable

  | id   |
--+------+
  | 101  |
--+------+
  | 102  |
--+------+
  | 103  |
```

How would I loop through and plug each of the returned id's into my function in a query. FOr this example just assume the default email is alwasy "myemail@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile so I can't test it, but I think maybe this will work.

```
SELECT * FROM (select my_function(id, 'myemail@gmail.com') from mytable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table mt 
  cross join lateral my_function(mt.id, 'myemail@gmail.com') as mf
```